# jQuery cycle plugin: zoom out and then fade

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle

I have an image slideshow and I want to make a specific transition between the images, but I don't know how, although I tried some different options. I am using jQuery Cycle plugin and what I want to achieve is: after couple of seconds first image gets a little bit bigger (not from the middle, it would move more towards left) and then it slowly fades into the next image and the next image would then have exactly the same transition. does anybody have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve this? I'm in the same situation...

Answer (score 0):

The nicest jQuery slideshow plugin i've came across *and* used is [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)

Comment: by the way i know this doesnt use the Cycle plugin but it could help nevertheless

Comment: thanks benhowdle89. i did have a look. unfortunately i need something which accepts images of different sizes..